# Книги о защите программ

Tags: c#, защита

Ищу по интернету книги c#, которые явно расскажут про защиту программ. Я не знаю, сколько методов взлома программ, поэтому прошу поделится названием книг.
Защита и безопасность одно и то же? Я думаю что безопасность больше всего строиться на защите информации пользователей.
Нашел книгу: ***Криптография и безопасность в технологии .NET***

Но там я думаю не то что мне нужно. Там как я понял шифрование например информации пользователя, аутентификация, обеспечение конфиденциальности информации, целостность информации и так далее. Конечно же меня интересует тема о защите пользователей, как раз эта книга наверное подойдет. Возможно я ошибаюсь и там есть еще и защита программ.
Я понимаю что мою программу рано или поздно взломают, да и наверное она не будет популярная, но все рано, рано или поздно взломают, да и хотелось бы очень озадачить взломщика.

Я знаю что можно использовать сервер, что бы большую часть логики кода исполнял он. Но например аутентификацию я думаю легко смогут обойти, удалить подключение к серверу и т.д. А большие коды, которые исполняются в многопоточном режиме будут тормозить сервер и клиент будет ожидать очень долго ответ от сервера. А если например каждую информацию которую проделала программа, выводить на экран пользователя? Я думаю что будет нужен мощный сервер.

*Приведите книги пожалуйста которые точно рассказывают о защите программ. Можно даже не на c#, но что бы я понимал как это делается. Нашел книги на форуме, но вопрос был задан 8 лет назад. Боюсь что там все устарело.*

Comment: Еще раз повторю: Забудьте про безопасность, если отдаете клиенту полный пакет всего. Отличный пример - игры, любой ААА проект берите и говорите, его взломали или нет? Вы только единицы найдете, которые не взломали и то, эти единицы будут очень тесно завязаны на сервере (то есть это клиент, который общается постоянно с сервером), есть умельцы, которые эмулируют сервер, но это очень трудоемкий процесс и мало кто за это берется. Так как вы хотите защитить свое приложение, если этого не могут сделать крупные гиганты? Хотите защиты - только сервер должен думать, остальные лишь давать ему команды.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Steinberg Cubase не использует сервер и ничего, живой ещё. Не сломали умельцы работу с USB Licenser :)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я так понимаю речь идет про [это](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdKEO.png)?

Comment: Если бы технически возможно было защитить надежно софт от пиратства, я думаю Microsoft бы давно это сделали со своей виндой.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не угадал. юсб на Cubase Pro......... А на LE_AI (точнее elements)  юсб не нужен и поэтому крякается вполне себе

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну... Спорить не буду, но уверен, софт либо свежий, либо слишком специфический (аля нужно оборудование, чтоб им пользоваться), либо сильно защищен юридически, либо он банально не нужен большому кругу людей. Если бы ваши эти `USB Licenser` были бы не ломаемыми, то их использовали бы наверно все, да? Я думаю, да. А пираты тем временем нашли бы лазейку, если бы это было у всех.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ не угадал ни с чем)))  Софт сверх популярный, на котором работают известные композиторы (например Ханс Циммер). Софт не специфичный - работает под виндой и уникальных драйверов и доп ПО **НЕ** требует. Скачал, поставил. Софту уже более 10 лет (а первая версия вышла 20 лет назад).  USB License они используют с версии 7 ЕМНИП (2012 год) с тех пор никто ещё пока не сломал. Поэтому пользуются версией 5.5 , потому что та ещё без USB (но понятно что там мало что потянет из плагинов)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ если бы все использовали USB Licenser то пользователи просто отказывались от такого софта, т.к. на 40 программ надо было бы 40 USB входов в компе :D

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Вы меня хотите переубедить или что? Я вашу точку зрения услышал, как и вы мою. Я бы поспорил с популярностью данного софта, может в узких кругах, среди "про" (из за чего ценник у нее в 50к), ну тогда зачем им пиратский софт? Их засудят за его использование. А простому люду, тратить такие деньги, ломать и так далее, ну не знаю, есть куча альтернатив, которыми все пользуются и создают свои шедевры. Да и уверен, что многие даже и не догадываются о существовании данной программы. Так что, я всеж думаю дело в спросе и потраченном на это времени и средствах простых граждан.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо, вас понял. Грустно конечно что так все складывается. 
Вот вы говорите про сервер, если моя программа слишком много данных принимает, обрабатывает, делает это все многопоточно, то как быть? Весь сложный и трудный код держать на сервере? А если моей программой будут пользоваться например 20 а то и 1000 людей? Сервер что ли не будет напрягаться?

Comment: @aepot хорошо! Вас понял. Думаю если даже тут и Microsoft не чего не могут сделать.. То печально.

Comment: @Komend Сколько посетителей у SO? А например гугл, яндекс, соц. сети? Спотифай. Это все ведь сервера с огромной аудиторией. Так что, ваш вопрос весьма странный...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, кхм.. Не подумал. Ладно, спасибо вам за поясняющий и краткий ответ!

Comment: мелкософты уже давно не на Windows зарабатывают. Не потому что их можно сломать, а потому что им выгоднее другое поле заработка - сопутствубщие услуги  и товары в маркетплейсе, реклама в приложениях и прочее. Они просто забили на защиту от взлома, потому что всё равно ось стОит копейки по-сути. Проще на оснвое этой оболки развернуть площадки для услуг, за которые получать гораздо больше

Comment: @АнтонМеталлов если вы правы, то скоро винда станет бесплатной.

Comment: @aepot Они уже давно нахаляву дают апгрейды до новой винды: 7->8, 8->10, 10->11.

Comment: @ГеннадийП невыгодно не давать, обновление парка систем в мире замедляется, а дольше поддерживать старые версии - дорого.